# gcc 4.9 fdiagnostics-color

Tags: ros, gcc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using gcc `4.9.3` and the `fdiagnostics-color` switch to produce colored output warning / error messages.
It works in a simple C++ CMake project but the output of `catkin_make` is not colored.

The flag is in the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` CMake cache:

```
$ cat build/CMakeCache.txt | grep CXX_FLAGS:
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING='-fdiagnostics-color  '
```

How do I get colored output from `catkin_make`? I don't want to use `colorgcc`.

**Edit 1:**

Using `make VERBOSE=1` I can tell the flag is here:

```
/usr/lib/ccache/c++   -fdiagnostics-color        CMakeFiles/bezier_application.dir/src/bezier_application.cpp.o  -o /home/dell/MEGAsync/catkin_workspace/devel/lib/bezier_application/bezier_application -rdynamic /home/dell/MEGAsync/catkin_workspace/devel/lib/libbezier_library.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib
```

Note that my non-catkin projects use `ccache` too and gets colored output.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227002/gcc-4.9-fdiagnostics-color/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2016-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-02-18**:
Just to check what's going wrong: Try catkin_make with VERBOSE=1 to see the g++ calls and if these get passed the flag.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2016-02-18**:
I edited my question to add more info. The flag is here as expected.

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2016-02-18**:
Try with `-fdiagnostics-color=always`. Maybe it will help.

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2016-02-18**:
Are you running both cmake and catkin_make under the same user?

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2016-02-18**:
`always` does not help. Yes, a non root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This happened because I was overwriting the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` flag in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

Old [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/bezier/blob/76d5c4cc80aa1ca66dea37fd07d38a464ad6cd5d/bezier_library/CMakeLists.txt#L2)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fPIC")
project(bezier_library)
```

Instead of `set`, use `add_compile_options`:

```
add_compile_options("-fPIC")
```

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2016-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3